# How can I add a print button to an InfoPath form? SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, development, javascript

I cannot create a print button that works in browser-enabled view. Is there any method make it. I have tried with thisXdocument.Print(), but thisXdocument does not exist in my context. I need to create that button inside form, not in a list!

thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

It might me a bit too late but thought it might be helpful for someone. https://arcemise.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/sharepoint-2010-infopath-print-button/#more-179